# How to delete array elements where there is a duplicate?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
  var countries= ["Egypt","Egypt","Ghana","Nigeria","Brazil","Brazil","Brazil"]

  var costs= [12,12,40,50,67,67,67]
```

I want to delete values in the 'costs' array where they match the index of a duplicate value in the 'countries' array. For example, there are 3 "Brazil" values, I want to delete the 'cost' elements after the index of the first "Brazil" value.

So the final arrays should look like:

```
var countries= ["Egypt","Egypt","Ghana","Nigeria","Brazil","Brazil", "Brazil"]

var costs= [12,,40,50,67,,]
```

Please note, I want to keep the length of the arrays the same.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: There is a missing "Brazil" in the final array, right?

Comment: Do you know how to find the indices of duplicates? Can you show us your code?

Comment: Add to a hashmap is one way to reduce duplicates.

Comment: Why did you remove the value from Egypt...? Please clarify

Comment: This seems quite trivial. Please show your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var countries= ["Egypt","Egypt","Ghana","Nigeria","Brazil","Brazil","Brazil"]

var costs= [12,12,40,50,67,67,67]

iterated = []
output = []
countries.forEach((element, index) => {
  iterated.push(element)
  const result = iterated.filter(e => e == element ); // filter and finds currents items in the already iterated array.
  if(result.length <= 1) { // if the lenth <=1 means there is no duplicate so push it to output
    output.push(costs[index])
  } else {
    output.push("") // if length greater than 1 means it is a duplicate, so push empty.
  }
 
});

console.log(output)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.